# php - different design of webpage for logged in users

Tags: php, logging

I just have one question. I looked through one book and the Internet and unfortunately didn't find an concrete answer. So... I have a webpage where user can log in. If the user is logged in then the bar at the top of webpage is different(user sees his own photo, name etc.). I know how to use sessions&databases in this case, but I don't know how to make  this two different websites. I mean.... in the home site of my whole webpage i can write sth like (in php):

```
if(isset($_SESSION["User"])) ..... .
```

But what then? I should somehow hide the html for unlogged user in "else" and part for logged user in "if" or should i create a whole new site for logged in users and redirect to this site if user is logged...? Please, help me.

Comment: Perhaps you just include a different CSS file for logged in users. Or different includes. There area  lot of ways to skin this cat.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you need to spend a little time looking into PHP deeper. My advice would be to learn about including PHP files in order to create a template system (so you would have a base PHP file with the HTML/PHP that is on every page (like a master page) that would include the code:

```
  if(isset($_SESSION["User"]))
  {
    // Do code for logged in user...
  }
  else
  {
     // Do code for generic user...
  }
```

Although that is a really rudimentary example, you could have a global variable if you need things on specific pages too. If you have a more specific question about implementing it, feel free to ask.

one cool thing that you can do in PHP is include html "inline". eg:

```
  if(isset($_SESSION["User"]))
  {
    ?>
    <p>Welcome User! <?php echo $_SESSION["User"]; ?></p>
    <?php
  }
  else
  {
    ?>
    <p>Please login to see all features...</p>
    <?php
  } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first set the session variable's value(eg. $_SESSION['logged_user_id']) to some value as per your website. Then assuming that you have only one page, you will have to include many php codes at the place you wanted to display user image, Hello xyzuser etc content. You will have to use "if/else" statements to check if the session variable for some user is set or not. If the session variable is set then it will be using the if block statements where you can write code to display image of the user corresponding to e.g. that logged_user_id using your db. Otherwise it will use the else part that will display your default content.
You will have to perform "if/else" checks at each place where your content has a chance to change based on the user status i.e. use the "if" statement to check if the user is logged in or not if no user is logged in then it won't go to the "if" block statements and execute the "else" part for default display. Ok.

Comment: Thanks, but actually that's what I wrote and I just asked if there is maybe other way of doing this than if & else. But I see that all of you responded for if&else, than, thanks, I will use it:)